# Xamarin.Forms Working with ListView from existing List of objects

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms and I am trying to create a ListView from c# List of my model, this is what I have tried...I created this view

```
<ListView x:Name="lst">
             <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <TextCell Text="{Binding Email}" />
                 </DataTemplate>
             </ListView.ItemTemplate>
         </ListView>
```

and I tried to set the ItemSource like so:

```
List<UserClass> users = new List<UserClass>();

            users = webService.getScannedLog();

            BindingContext = this;
            lst.ItemsSource = users;
```

but when I do this, I get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would be curious to know what do you think about my second post/answer to your question (also, if any of those answers solved your problem, please do not forget to mark it as THE ANSWER, so that that is reflected in the feed)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the binding for ItemsSource:

```
<ListView x:Name="lst"
          ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
             <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <TextCell Text="{Binding Email}" />
                 </DataTemplate>
             </ListView.ItemTemplate>
         </ListView>
```

And in the code behind:

```
List<UserClass> users = new List<UserClass>();

            users = webService.getScannedLog();

            BindingContext = users;
```

Note that ItemsSource binding was set in XAML.

Comment: How will it know to use the user List?

Comment: I edited my answer. If you still have doubts, please let me know.

Comment: My pleasure! Please do not forget to set this post as Answer ;)

Comment: there is no reason you can't set ItemsSource directly in code

Comment: @Jason, no one said "you can't set ItemsSource directly in code". I just used my own style and pointed that out in my post by telling user979331 to "Note that ItemsSource binding was set in XAML".

Comment: you specifically said "You have to set the binding for ItemsSource:" - which is not true.  I'm glad you helped OP fix his problem, but your solution is really no different than what they were doing originally, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Jason, now i get your point! Thanks for mentioning that! I posted a second answer trying to figure out how THIS answer did fix the problem if, as you commented above, my code does basically the same as that in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Motivated by the comment of @Jason on my first answer to this post i got curious to know if he was right when he said:

> there is no reason you can't set ItemsSource directly in code

and after a bit of research i found out that as he pointed out, the code in my answer was doing fundamentally the same as the code of the OP. But... how did then my answer help OP to solve the problem?

Well, the only way i can get the exception

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

using the code in the original post is if the c# code posted is called before `InitializeComponent()` is called, that is, if the code behind looks like:

```
public MainPage()
{

    List<UserClass> users = new List<UserClass>();

    users = webService.getScannedLog();

    BindingContext = this;
    lst.ItemsSource = users;

    InitializeComponent();

}
```

in which case `lst` is being called before it is even created by `InitializeComponent()`.
In that case, my answer solved the issue by removing `lst` reference and setting `ItemsSource` directly in **XAML**.

If that is the case, at all, then i would like to say that to solve the issue it is enough to move the setting of `ItemsSource` after the call to `InitializeComponent()`, in which case the code would look something like:

```
public MainPage()
{

    InitializeComponent();    

    List<UserClass> users = new List<UserClass>();

    users = webService.getScannedLog();

    BindingContext = this;
    lst.ItemsSource = users;

}
```

@user979331, please let me know if this is the case.